# How Get Key Value From Json Encoded Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

How i Access LocalId Key Value in Php. This Array is Json Endcoded

```
{"0":{"kind":"identitytoolkit#VerifyPasswordResponse","localId":"u0iuiF09idQ1pEl0oJTfElqTtXr1"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = json_decode($your_string, true); // assign it to a variable
echo $arr[0]["localId"]; // --> your question
```

Comment: He is asking about an array while his code contains an object, This will work instead `echo $arr->0->localid;`

Comment: -> operator will work on an object. true parameter to json_decode makes it array not object.